# Querying GROUP BY on 1+ billion rows in MemSQL

Tags: sql, bigdata, database-performance, singlestore

I have a table with 1.3 billion rows (MemSQL, columnstore pattern). I need to query a GROUP BY on 3 fields (id1, id2, text) and fetch the latest record for each of this 3-tuple. The table gets populated through a pipeline mounted onto a EFS folder. Currently, it has about 200k csv files of 2MB each.

I need help writing an optimized query for this case or if it can be done some other way.

Edit: I am not able to find any blog/help online, most of them talk about solutions involving the creation of an extra table which is not possible for me now (very heavy memory usage in that case).

Something like below is not going to work and takes my 5-node cluster down:

`select max(eventTime) from table1 group by id1, id2, field1`

Comment: Show your try-code.

Comment: @R.García The question is more about how to approach with the grouping of such a number of rows rather than how to write the query. Do you think details like `select max(eventTime) from table1 group by id1, id2, field1` will help? Not at all.

Comment: @umeshksingla - the question is somewhat open ended and asking for a 'recommendation'.

Comment: @Andrew Can you help me with what more can I provide?

Comment: @umeshksingla - schema details including index details, query plan of the query which is not suitable for you, showing why it is not suitable. e.g. Provide specifics. Of the 1.3 bn records, how many unique tuples are there? data historgram information may also help understand better options.

Comment: If your system cannot handle the `GROUP BY`, I would be surprised if it could handle any similar query on the data.

Comment: What is the table schema? Consider adding a shard key on some of those columns. You'll also want to check your logs for information about why it's taking the cluster down. What error is it? That could indicate e.g. a misconfiguration of memory limits which causes linux to oom kill the memsql nodes.

Answer (score 0):

there a couple of considerations here.
1) what is your shard key for the columnstore table?
2) are you using MemSQL 6.5, the most recent version?
3) have you reviewed this resource about Optimizing Table Data Structures? https://www.memsql.com/static/memsql_whitepaper_optimizing_table_data_structures.pdf

Ensure that common columns for all queries in the columnstore key to improve segment elimination.
If the data is inserted in an order, like a timestamp, it's best to put that column first in the columnstore key to minimize the work of the background merger process.
If there are lots of distinct values in one of the keys of the composite key, put that last. Put the key part with less distinctness first to increase the likelihood that segment elimination will be able to affect later columns.

Also, what would help is if run ran 
`EXPLAIN select max(eventTime) from table1 group by id1, id2, field1;`
so that we could see the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

It takes long time because it needs a proper design for the database. So you have to choose the shard key to be those three columns (id1,id2,field1). I recommend to use column store for that query rather than row store.